# Getting nill UITableviewcell from indexpath

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I am getting nil UITableviewcell,check my below code.

```
  int random = arc4random() % arr.count;                                     
  NSInteger index = [[arr objectAtIndex:random-1] integerValue];
  NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0];
  SongListCell *cell2 = (SongListCell *)[table_view cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
```

- Getting nill cell.

what is wrong? what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Where did you put this code?

Comment: i create a function and put this code inside.

Answer (score 0):

Method `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` returns nil if cell is not visible or index path is out of range

Comment: if i will pass any random number like 5 in indexpath  (NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:5 inSection:0];) insted of index than i can get cell but when i am trying with NSInteger or int Value than i am getting nill. why?

Comment: It means your cell at index 5 is visible and `cellForRowAtIndexPath :` return cell, cell at random index may not visible so you are getting nil

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve, but I think that maybe the second row of your code shouldn't be there. Is that possible? Shouldn't it be:

```
  int random = arc4random() % arr.count;                                     
  NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:random-1 inSection:0];
  SongListCell *cell2 = (SongListCell *)[table_view cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
```

Because otherwise, your depending on the values inside `arr` and not just on the amount of objects in `arr`, and these values may contain invalid indices (or maybe even non numeric ones).

If that's not the case, can you please provide an example of values from `arr`?

Comment: Actually i have an array contain with 4 objects, arr = [NSArray arraywithobjects:@"3",@"4",@"7",@"9"]; And these are row index so i am trying to get random value from that array count and that value will be indexpath of uitableview. if i get 2 random number than indexpathforrow will be 4. but still getting nil cell.

Comment: Can you check what value you're receiving for "index"? Is it indeed a valid row number?

Answer (score 0):

You should create the cell yourself if it is nil, alternatively in your `viewDidLoad` or where appropriate, you can call one of these methods to make the tableview create the cells for you.

```
[self.tableView registerClass:<#(__unsafe_unretained Class)#> forCellReuseIdentifier:<#(NSString *)#>]
[self.tableView registerNib:<#(UINib *)#> forCellReuseIdentifier:<#(NSString *)#>]
```